# width of spark label

Tags: apache-flex

I need to set the text of a spark label and then position such label along the x axis depending on its width. Unfortunately, it seems that the width of the label does not update right away and thus the positioning will fail. I can listen to updateComplete events on the label and update its position then, but that means repositioning the label a lot more often than I would like (updateComplete fires off a lot more often than upon changing width). Any ideas on how to properly handle what would appear to be a trivial task?

Here's a code snippet that shows what I described above. If you press the button you will see 3 traces: the label width before changing its text, right after setting its text, and when the label is done updating itself. Would love to know if there's a way to get the correct width without having to listen to updateComplete events... The button and the VGroups are just there to run the example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace("label width = ", lb.width);
                lb.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, lb_updateCompleteHandler);
                lb.text = "hello world!";
                trace("label width post change= ", lb.width);
            }

            protected function lb_updateCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                lb.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, lb_updateCompleteHandler);
                trace("label width post update complete = ", lb.width);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Button label="go" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <s:Label id="lb" text="h" x="10" y="10" />
    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: I don't understand your desired layout, can you try to explain in different words how you want things to appear, and how they actually are appearing?

Comment: I want the label to have an x position that depends on its width. That's a bit generic, but not that hard to imagine I hope...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I mean: what should the end result look like? Perhaps you could post a screenshot. I have a feeling you're trying to do something the hard way, but I can't know.

Comment: I think you're right, I am trying to do things the hard way and stumbled upon what I think is an interesting generic question about labels. The end goal: I have a label that needs to be to the left of a bunch of other stuff. The label can change length, and the stuff can grow or shrink. I guess an HGroup would take care of business for me, but I was trying to stay away from automated layout (I'm working on optimizing some item renderers) and thought I could handle positioning the label on my own (shouldn't be that hard after all). thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're talking about optimization of item renderer you'd better write your own ActionScript-based item renderer with `mx.core.UIFTETextField` or `mx.core.UITextField` inside which positioned in `updateDisplayList()`.

Comment: fair enough. As of now I'm writing my own IR in AS with labels and was planning on moving to UIFTETextField at some point soon, but maybe that time has come...

Comment: I don't think HGroup is going to give you much of a performance hit, since it was created to perform better than the old HBox. HBox had to draw stuff, but HGroup only calculates and updates positions. You would essentially just be rewriting that. Perhaps you could leave out some calculations that aren't necessary to you, but I really don't think there's much to gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like listening to resize events does the trick and is not quite as general as updateComplete events, so I'm calling that the "correct answer". There may be a better way to do this when you're trying to position stuff by hand due to performance optimization, although I'm not sure what it is yet.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me. Simple yet works.

```
var l:Label = new Label();
l.text = "That'll do";
var tlm:TextLineMetrics = l.measureText( l.text);
Alert.show( tlm.width + " is what you are looking for");
```

Answer (score 1):

`VGroup` is a `Group` with `VerticalLayout`. It doesn't allow to have custom positioning inside group (with `x` and `y`). To have this possibility use `Group` with (default) `BasicLayout`.

Comment: sorry - VGroup has nothing to do with the question, it was just a way to position the button and the label independently. will edit the question - I clearly did a poor job at writing it :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a [callLater()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#callLater%28%29), you can "capture" variables in the current scope, but also have it execute after the change in the `width` has been propagated.  For example:

```
callLater(function():void
      {
        trace("label width in callLater = ", lb.width);
      });
```

**UPDATE**:  I think I should elaborate a little more to make clear what I meant by "capturing" values.  This can be done with the following simple illustration:

```
callLater(function(prevWidth:Number):void
      {
        trace("previous label width in callLater = ", prevWidth);  // 8
        trace("label width in callLater = ", lb.width);  // 64
      }, [lb.width]);
```

As the example demonstrates, the parameters that you pass in through the `args` Array (, i.e., the `[lb.width]` which becomes `prevWidth`) take the current value (ie., they pass by value), whereas, the variables you make direct reference to in the function are actually in the scope when the function gets executed (ie., a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)).

You could do this with the event listener also, but with the callLater() it's a little simpler.

Answer (score -1):

You can call lb.validateNow() after setting text, this way you will get new width right away. But suggest you to read about components lifecycle not to have such trivial questions.

And yes, as people pointed out already, no repositioning will work with such layout.

Comment: I had tried validateNow but surprisingly doesn't seem to do the trick in this case - not sure why. As I mentioned in my re-edit the layout has nothing to do with the question...